# Channel selection with sox

Tags: sox

Assuming I only want one channel in the output file, is

`sox in.wav out.wav -c 1`

equivalent to

`sox in.wav out.wav remix 1-n`, `n` being the number of input channels

Answer (score 1):

The `sox` manpage says:

> `channels CHANNELS`
>
> Invoke a simple algorithm to change the number  of  channels  in
>   the  audio  signal  to  the  given  number  CHANNELS:  mixing if
>   decreasing the number of channels or duplicating  if  increasing
>   the number of channels.
>
> The  channels effect is invoked automatically if SoX's `-c` option
>   specifies a number of channels that is different to that of  the
>   input  file(s).

So it's not equivalent (`channels` instead of `remix`), but the result is the same.